# error: package directory 'argparse' does not exist

Tags: python, build, executable, argparse

I need to build an executable Python scripts. So I run "python setup.py build" , the error message shows in the below :

running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'argparse' does not exist

In my setup.py, below are the codes:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable("word_search_puzzle.py")]

setup(
    name = "Word Search Puzzle",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "A Word Search Puzzle Generator",
    executables = executables,
    packages = ['argparse']
)
```

So I have tried, installed/reinstalled argparse.
I have tried rebooting my computer as well.
I checked my Python version is 3.11.1 which should have included the argparse.
My scripts are perfectly fine. I am not sure what else to be done.

Comment: `argparse` is a standard part of python, and has been for a long time.  You shouldn't be trying to install it - the pypi version probably is out of date, or at least out of sequence from the standard.  And it shouldn't need any special setup reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `packages` variable in `setup()` is for compiling your own packages from a code directory, not for installing packages. You don't need to include it when building an executable, simply having the package installed from `pip` should be enough.

Comment: Yeah. I was a bit confused at first, now it started to make sense. Thanks @flexagoon